# A simple JS madlib program not working

Tags: javascript

I've written a Madlib programme in JS with bootstrap. When user will input value, the complete story will be appeared in a bootstrap modal. But it's not working. The modal is appearing full empty. Please help me to find out what is going wrong. The code is in below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A simple Madlib game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">A simple MadLib game</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="story_div"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h2 class="text-center">A simple JavaScript MadLib game</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">An adjective</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adjOne" placeholder="such as: large, rusty, old etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">An animal name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="animalOne" placeholder="such as: cow, monkey, lion etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A verb (Past tense)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="verbPastOne" placeholder="such as: laughed, walked etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">An adverb</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adverbOne" placeholder="such as: always, carefully, barefooted etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Another adjective</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adjTwo" placeholder="such as: large, rusty, old etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A noun</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="noun" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A noun</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nounTwo" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">An adjective</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adjThree" placeholder="such as: large, rusty, old etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A verb</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="verb" placeholder="such as: always, carefully, barefooted etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">An adverb</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adverbTwo" placeholder="such as: always, carefully, barefooted etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">A verb (Past tense)</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="verbPastTwo" placeholder="such as: laughed, walked etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">An adjective</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adjFour" placeholder="such as: large, rusty, old etc.">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="button" id="launch" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch story</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            var adjOne = document.querySelector("#adjOne");
            var animalOne = document.querySelector("#animalOne");
            var verbPastOne = document.querySelector("#verbPastOne");
            var adverbOne = document.querySelector("#adverbOne");
            var adjTwo = document.querySelector("#adjTwo");
            var noun = document.querySelector("#noun");
            var nounTwo = document.querySelector("#nounTwo");
            var adjThree = document.querySelector("#adjThree");
            var verb = document.querySelector("#verb");
            var adverbTwo = document.querySelector("#adverbTwo");
            var verbPastTwo = document.querySelector("#verbPastTwo");
            var adjFour = document.querySelector("#adjFour");
            var launch = document.querySelector("#launch");
            launch.addEventListener("click", writeStory, false);

            function writeStory(){
                launchedStory = "";
                launchedStory += "<p>Today I went to the zoo. I saw a(n) " + adjOne.value + " " + animalOne.value + " jumping up and down in its tree.<p>";
                launchedStory += "<p>He " + verbPastOne.value + " " + adverbOne.value + " through the large tunnel that led to its " + adjTwo.value + " " + noun.value + ".<p>";
                launchedStory += "<p>I got some peanuts and passed them through the cage to a gigantic gray " + nounTwo.value + " towering above my head. Feeding that animal made me                   hungry<p>";
                launchedStory += "<p>I went to get a " + adjThree.value + " scoop of ice cream. It filled my stomach.<p>";
                launchedStory += "<p>Afterwards I had to " + verb.value + " " + adverbTwo.value + " to catch our bus.<p>";
                launchedStory += "<p>When I got home I " + verbPastTwo.value + "  my mom for a " + adjFour.value + " day at the zoo.<p>";

                story_div.innerHTML = launchedStory;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your JavaScript console for any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a look at your at the javascript console, you would see the issues directly (try *F12* on your favorite browser).

They all are due to misspelling errors.

1. Write `"#verbPastOne"` instead of `"#verPastOne"`
2. Write `"#verbPastTwo"` instead of `"#verPastTwo"`

And, last but not least...

3. Write `verbPastOne.value` instead of `verbPastOne.Value`

Yes JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, now it is fixed. There was some spelling mistake and case sensitive mistake. Thank you